# Confine all jQuery selectors to children of a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, css-selectors

I certainly know how to select confine a jQuery selector to children of a particular element each time I make the selection (i.e. $('#left ul') selects all ul that are children of #left). While that's simple enough, if I'm going to perform a bunch of operations to various children of #left, it's a bit cumbersome to have to keep writing $('#left ul'), $('#left p'), $('#left ...'). Instead, I'd prefer to just be able to temporarily confine the potential selectors to only children of #left. For example:

```
...some code that established #left as the "scope" of any future selectors;
$('ul').css(...); //actually selects $('#left ul')
$('p').css(...); //actually selects $('#left p')

...some code that re-established the full DOM as the "scope";
$('ul').css(...); //selects all ul, not just children of #left
$('p').css(...); //selects all p, not just children of #left
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rely on context and find.

```
var $l = $('#left')
  , ul = $l.find('ul')
  , p = $l.find('p');
```

Comment: Actually your l variable is already a jQuery object. So you can just say ul = l.find('ul'). No need to re-wrap it.

Comment: I'm aware of that, doesn't always appear in my answers though.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This doesn't really speed up the coding process though. Now you're just stuck writing $l.find(...) every time rather than $('#left ...') every time. Any idea which one is faster though? I'd guess $('#left ...'), but I'm not basing that on much :)

Comment: l.find('ul') is faster than $('#left ul') or even $('#left').find('ul') (assuming you already found l) since you don't have to find #left elements again.

Comment: Could you clarify your question if meder's answer isn't what you're looking for? As Adilson mentions, you can always specify a context as the second parameter. Is that more what you're looking for?

Comment: I think you're going a bit over the edge. jQuery already saves you from typing `getElementsByTagName('ul')` which becomes `ul`, next people will want everything done magically in a one liner... The second param context is slower behind the scenes, and is pretty much the same thing. It would not be a wise idea to override the default behaviour.. just use what's there.

Comment: James -- my question is based solely on the desire to make my coding a bit faster (i.e. type less) and more readable. Adilson's method doesn't accomplish this, and neither does meder's. I'm certainly not faulting them, since it's quite possible that what I'm trying to achieve isn't doable.

Comment: @madedison - I suggest using vim if you want to code faster. That will dramatically increase your output of code moreso than your current text editor ( unless you are using vim ) and would be more significant than hacking jQuery.

Comment: Meder -- "going a bit over the edge" is relative to the person doing the coding and the project at hand. Is this a critical thing I need? Absolutely not. It would just be nice. jQuery itself provides shortcuts for achieving things that would be fairly easily achievable through other methods it provides. Anyway, I'm assuming at this point that I can't do what I had originally asked. No big deal.

Comment: You can hack the source to do it, but it would cause unwanted behaviour and your subsequent code would break unless you fixed it. It would cause confusion if you pasted snippets on Stackoverflow, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The "$" method can receive 2 arguments: the selector and the context. So, you can use the following syntax:

```
$('.children_selector',$('.the_parent_selector'))
```

But, to avoid the $(selector,context) usage. You can write a function, "overriding" the $ function, and write your code inside. Take a look:

```
            (function($)
            {
                //here the $ selects the elements inside the first element with the class xpto
            })(function(a){return $(a,$('.xpto')[0]);});
```

Anyway, I would dislike to find this kind of construction. For maintenance purposes is better to get more line of codes than fewer lines of obscure code.